# Организация базы данных для приложения

Tags: база-данных

Пишу веб-приложение. Встал вопрос организации структуры бд для разных типов пользователей. Недоумеваю как сделать это наилучшим образом, чтобы потом не переделывать. Планируется создать несколько типов пользователей: "администратор", "стандартный пользователь", "модератор"... У каждого типа имеются как свои поля, так и общие для всех. Как же лучше всего построить бд?

Comment: Сколько общих полей?

Comment: Какие именно "свои" поля есть у каждого типа пользователей? Опишите поля каждого типа пользователей, чтоб понимать

Comment: общие поля: id, username, email, password, <timestamps>. У модератора поле администратора, который назначил роль этому модератору.

Answer (score 0):

Если методов не много тогда просто флаги

```
0x00000001 - может логинится
0x00000002 - может писать посты
0x00000004 - может модерировать
0x00000008 - может зайти в админку
```

1+2+4+8 (получает все привелегии)

Если методов планируеться много то создай табличку Permissions, Roles, Permission2Role

Где будет

```
Permissions:
# Название      действие1   действие2   действие3
1 is.user       Y           N           N
2 is.moderator  Y           Y           Y 

Roles:
# Название      parent
1 User          NULL
2 Moderator     1

Permission2Role:
#роль   #содержит
1       1
2       2
```

тогда читаешь деревом все наследственности и переписываешь их более верхним способом

Минус такой таблички - что при изменении 1 из ролей надо перечитать все дерево и закешировать permission

Comment: роли в моем случае не только говорят о правах, но и несут какую-то информацию в себе.

Comment: На всамом деле это заплетистая система и она себя шикарно реализует когда ролей много что-то типо начальник отдела 3 и его подчиненные, начальник отдела 4 и его подчиненные, зам директора, директор... Для небольших сайтов я обычно создаю очень широкую табличку флагов а-ля login_flags, moderator_flags, admin_flags, session_flags и.т.д.

Comment: этот способ решает немного другую задачу. А что, если я хочу добавить какому нибудь типу пользователя какое-нибудь информационное поле, которое отсутствует в других типах пользователей. Например, на одном сервисе присутствуют клиенты и сотрудники. Они выполняют одинаковую регистрацию. Администратор меняет роль какому-нибудь пользователю на "сотрудник" и для него уже нужны поля "отдел" и "опыт работы". Как все это представить в таблицах базы данных? Создать таблицы со своими полями под каждую роль?